# send html email using OneDrive Graph api

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, onedrive

How do I send HTML content from OneDrive Graph Api /sendMail endpoint?  I have tried various permutations of HTML and encoded HTML in the body but I never receive HTML in the actual email.

-- Edit --

It turns out my problem is actually Outlook Online stripping unsafe HTML.  If I include a link to Bing.com that gets stripped, if I include a link copied from one of my automated Teams emails that does not get stripped.

I have trawled the Office 365 Security and Compliance but found nothing to flag specific domains as safe.

If anyone knows how to mark domains as safe, or some other solution that would be great.

Comment: It looks like you have a specific issue (not receive HTML in your actual email).  Great!  Reproducible.  To that end, could you share what your input was so that we can reproduce your unexpected output?  Also, you mention "numerous samples".  Perhaps you could share 1 or 2 of these so that we have a common context for discussion?

Comment: Yes i agree with @RazzleShazl. Share the related info(including the sample or Graph API call with the workload or detailed steps), so that we can help.